# CSV export with the wrong character set (utf-8 ?)

Tags: newmips

I have exported the data is CSV format but it contains funny character like Ã©, Ã¯Â»Â¿.

What is the charset? UTF-8 or the one of my computer?
Is there a way to specify the charset at export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unfortunately impossible to specify Charset at the export... But I think you can define encoding during CSV import process in LibreOffice or MS Excel. Tell me if it solves your issue.

Comment: To open Excel to import csv/UTF-8 and export to csv/latim-1 is not a solution. I am using Pentaho Data Integrator which also solves the issue, and many more.